# Ignoring links within columns

Tags: jquery

I have a table I am searching for data within. I can find the data fine but I am using `.each` to iterate over each row. Currently I am using `text()` which returns all the text in each column of the row. I am then checking this text.

However, I want to ignore certain columns within a row. In this case if the column contains a link rather than just text.

How can I change my code to account for this?

```
<table class=table-name>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stuff I want to search</td>
            <td>Stuff I want to search</td>
            <td><a href="somelink.com" class="some-class">Link text I don't want to search</a></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

code

```
var row = $(".table-name").find("tbody").find("tr");
var input = 'Link text';

row.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("hide", false);
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("hide", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out text using:

```
$(this).children('td:not(:has(a))').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.each` is on rows, not on columns.
Also, you're lowercasing the text, but using a mixed case input search... So Something like this works instead...

```
var row = $(".table-name").find("tbody").find("tr");
var input = 'Link text';

row.children().each(function() {
    if ( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("hide", false);
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("hide", true);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71mytwe0/1/